# Solution of Differential Equation-confusion-

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We are trying to solve $\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{1}{x}y  = \frac{1}{x^2}y^2$ for $y$ where $y(1) = 1$.

I had thought we needed to get this in for the form of $\frac{dy}{dt} + p(t)y = g(t)$, but that is not possible.

I tried integrating $\frac{dy}{dx}$ alone, but I don't think that is correct since I get:

\begin{equation}y = y\ln(x) - \frac{1}{2}y^2\ln(x^2) + C\end{equation}

which doesn't seem like it would be my answer.

The problem is that this equation isn't seperable. Right? I can't split it up into the form $N(y)\frac{dy}{dx} = M(x)$

Answer (score 1):

This equation is called Bernoulli equation. Let $z=y^{-1}$ and hence $z'=-y^{-2}y'$ and then multiply both by $-y^{-2}$ to be a linear equation in $z$. If you could not solve the new linear one, just let me know.

Comment: http://www.princeton.edu/~asmits/Bicycle_web/Bernoulli.html That is a Bernoulli Equation? Or well, how did you know that the equation was a Bernoulli equation. Ah, http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Bernoulli.aspx

Comment: the general form is $y'+p(x)y=q(x)y^n$ and the solution the substitution $z=y^{1-n}$

Comment: second link is good

Comment: just try it and let me help you whenever you face any problem

Comment: So, we originally have $\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{1}{x}y = -\frac{1}{x^2}y^2$. Dividing by $y^2$ we find $y^{-2}\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{1}{x}y^{-1} = - \frac{1}{x^2}$ and we let $v = y^{-1}$. Then $\frac{dv}{dy} = -y^{-2}$ and $dv = -y^{-2}dy$. My question is, how I am supposed to substitute this in. We have $y^{-2}\frac{dy}{dx}$, but not $y^{-2}dy$

Comment: $v=y^{-1}$ then $\frac{dv}{dx}=-y^{-2} \frac{dy}{dx}$, notice the difference

Comment: $\frac{dv}{dx}$? We aren't taking the derivative of $v$ with respect to $x$. We are taking it with respect to $y$. Aren't we?

Comment: both $v$ and $y$ are functions of the independent variable $x$ and we differentiate both sides w.r.t $x$

Comment: I suppose they are functions of $x$ implicitly. Is that right? That they are functions of $x$ because they are implicitly defined to be functions of $x$

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Divide by $xy^2$ and obtain
$$
\frac{1}{xy^2}\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{1}{x^2y}  = \frac{1}{x^3}
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{x}(y^{-1})' - \frac{1}{x^2}y^{-1}  = \frac{1}{x^3},
$$
or
$$
\left(\frac{1}{xy}\right)'=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)'
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{xy}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x^2}+c,
$$
with $c=3/2$, using the initial data.